# [ Solved ]: Cannot find version 14 of OpenJDK for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: jdk, openjdk, 20.04

**As of today (May 6th, 2020), the problem described below is now obsolate, because OpenJDK-14 has finally appeared in Ubuntu 20.04 repository.**

---

I've installed Ubuntu **20.04** Focal Fossa and was trying to install the latest Java JDKs in both flavours: OpenJDK and Oracle.
However, searching via apt search gives **OpenJDK (and also JRE) only up to 11th edition**.

Searching on https://packages.ubuntu.com/ **narrowed to focal** distribution also gives results up to **openjdk-11**-jXX.
Switching the distribution of choice to **eoan**, gives all up to date versions including **14**th.

I'm not asking how to enforce the installation of exactly 14th edition of OpenJDK, but rather for the reason for this?
Is it due to any security reasons and I should also get rid of 14th Oracle version (downgrade it to 11th)?
Or just patiently wait because OpenJDK-14 need to be approved for Focal Fossa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is simply not done yet. If you go to "Software & Updates" and enable "Developer Options" / "Pre-released updated (focal-proposed)", the package shows up.

Here's what I did to get the package:

- Checked the checkbox
- sudo apt update
- (ignore all the other proposed updates)
- sudo apt install openjdk-14-jdk
- Unchecked the checkbox
- sudo apt update
- (observer that the other proposed updates are now gone)

I don't know if that is a good recommendation, but it worked for me to get a java-14 installation on my machine :)

Comment: Thanks, but for safety reasons I'll temporarily stay with Oracle version until OpenJDK-14 will be officially available for Focal Fossa. Fortunately, there's update-alternatives with which it could be seamlessly switched.